# Styling the ratingbar breaks the scale?

Tags: android, xml, ratingbar

I've been trying for days now to style my rating bar and googling how to fix it, when I use the action bar like this:

```
<RatingBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:numStars="5"
            android:rating="3"
            android:isIndicator="true"
            android:id="@+id/rating"
            style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
            />
```

I get this result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWUHk.png (I can't post images yet),
so when I write my own style and do it like:

```
<RatingBar
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="25dp"
android:numStars="5"
android:rating="3"
android:isIndicator="true"
android:id="@+id/rating"
style="@style/ratingBar"/>
```

Where ratingBar is defined in styles.xml as:

```
<style name="ratingBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/ratingstars</item>
</style>
```

and ratingstars is defined in drawable/ratingstars.xml as:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:drawable="@drawable/staroff"/>
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/staroff"/>
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/progress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/staron"/>
</layer-list>
```

The staron and staroff are pngs with the desired textures for the stars, the result I get is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvK8z.png
How would I get it to be the same size as the ratingbar in first example, yet use the textures I provided?

I've tried using scaleX and scaleY, which cut the stars and messed up their positioning, setting width is not an option since there'd be more than 5 stars, so what can I do here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use custom images you will need to change size of images.

If you want to just change the color of stars there is a possibility to do it with code.

```
    RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar)view.findViewById(R.id.rating);
    LayerDrawable stars = (LayerDrawable) ratingBar.getProgressDrawable();
    stars.getDrawable(0).setColorFilter(Color.GRAY, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
    stars.getDrawable(1).setColorFilter(Color.GRAY, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
    stars.getDrawable(2).setColorFilter(Color.BLACK, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

In this example the star that shows rating will be black color and others will be gray.

Don't forget to set the style of RatingBar to small.
Example:

```
style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.RatingBar.Small"
```

In this case you won't need "drawable/ratingstars.xml" and style in "styles.xml".